# Shutdown a locked XP Computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that shuts down a Windows XP computer at 6:00pm every day using the following command:

```
shutdown.exe /s /t 600 /c "Windows will shutdown in 10 minutes. To cancel shutdown, click Start and type 'shutdown /a'."
```

The command works as expected except when the user has locked the workstation with Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Is there a way to shutdown a computer even when the user has locked it?

**UPDATE:** The documentation for the `/f` parameter reads:

> Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
>     The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
>     specified for the /t parameter.

From that, I assume that it is set already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isn't there a `/f` flag that forces it to shutdown?

Comment: Turns out the `/f is implied` is BS. I added that and it works.

Comment: Good discovery.  I did not know that.

Answer (score 6):

You can indeed use the /f flag to force shutdown. But what I like better, is psshutdown ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx ).

Psshutdown can be used locally AND remote. I personally use the remote shutdown to reboot and apply updates at scheduled times. Shutdown.exe allows you to show a message, but psshutdown has an option to even show a "abort shutdown" button. Which is way more userfriendly.